How to extend a function from the Riemannian manifold to the Euclidean space?
Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a Riemannian manifold embedded in the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$.
We can assume that $\mathcal{M}$ is complete and compact if necessary.
Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a lower semi-continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $g: \mathcal{M} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a lower semi-continuous on $\mathcal{M}$.
Suppse that $g$ is continuously differentiable in a neighborhood of $X \in \mathcal{M}$ and $f - g$ attains a local minimum at $X$ on $\mathcal{M}$.
Can we smoothly extend the function $g$ from $\mathcal{M}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $g$ is continuously differentiable near $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f - g$ attains a local minimum at $X$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$?
Thanks in advance!

Is it relevant that $\mathcal{M}$ is a Riemannian manifold?
